# Load files from folder with a custom query with power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to load csv files from a folder **but I need to apply several custom steps to each file**, including dropping the `PromoteHeaders` default.

I have a custom query that can load a single file successfully. How do I turn it into a query that loads all files in a folder?

By default, `File.folder`'s "promoteHeaders" messes up my data because of a missing column name (which my custom query fixes).

Comment: Create a function and apply that function for each file. The function should handle all the transformation and only return the parsed table so you can expand.

Comment: @mxix I figured it is what I needed to do but was not able to find documentation. Could you please point me in the right direction? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to create a function that reads a specific template of file is to actually do it. Just create the M to read it and by right click on the entity transform it to a function.

After that is really simple to transform your M so it uses parameters.

You can create a blank query and replace the code with this on as an example, customize with more steps to deal with your file requirements.

```
= (myFile) => let
        Source = Csv.Document(myFile,[Delimiter=",", Columns=33, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])
    in
        Source
```

And then **Invoke Custom Function** for each file with the content as the parameter.